# Comparing items in an char array table in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, character

I included the given snippet in my code:

```
char in[n][3];
for(int i=0;i<noc;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
          cin>>in[i][j];
        }
     }
for(int i=0;i<noc;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<noc;j++){
         if(in[i]!=in[j][1]){
            nod+=1;
         }
   }
     }
```

Now the compiler says"ISO C++ does not allow comparing pointers with integers"
What is the logis here??

Comment: The problem is here: `in[j]!=in[k][1]`. Is that intended, or a mistake?

Comment: The error is coming from the line having
[code]  if(in[j]!=in[k][1])

Comment: @juanchopanza Yea...I think I am wrong there ...How should I correct it??

Comment: Where is that `k` coming from, out of curiosity? Likewise with the `n`

Comment: It should be something like `in[j][x]!=in[k][1]`, where `x` is an index you should know how to set, since it is your algorithm :-)

Comment: Well n is constant. It is retrieved via standard input and passed on to the function.

Comment: This is the actual code..Now compiler flags the same error.

Comment: See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This is not *all* the actual code *we need*. You got the short part, but this is not self-contained, nor compilable as-is. Without more information  from *you* nothing else can be offered up. You're comparing a second-dimension vector to a first-dimension value, which is not possible. Thats about all that can be said.

Comment: Is there a reason that you chose a char array over a std::vector<std::string>?

Answer (score 1):

in[i] is a pointer to line i, in[j][1] is char. You can't compare them directly unless you explicitly cast them to int or something else.

Comment: You can't compare them *at **all*** and remain in the confines of the language.